# Length of state array is not changeable in Solidity

Tags: solidity, state-variable

Consider there are 3 contracts: BankA, customer, and BankB.BankA transfers some ethers to customer and after that some customer's state variables must be changed (in a better words be updated). It must also happen for BankB and customer. But the changes are not stable and their values return back to default.

customer:

```
pragma solidity^0.5.12;
contract customer{
  address payable[]  public onboarded;
  bytes public fullname;
  bytes public id;
  bool public KYC;
  uint256 public categor;
  function prime(bytes memory fname, bytes memory iden, bool KYCresult, uint256 level, address payable bank) public{
    fullname=fname;
    id=iden;
    KYC=KYCresult;
    categor=level;
    onboarded.push(bank);
  }
  function() external payable{}
  }
function Array() public returns(uint256){
return onboarded.length;
}
```

BankA==BankB:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;

import "./customer.sol";
contract BankA{
  function creation() public returns(string memory){
    customer client=new customer();
    client.prime("Alireza Kiakojouri","5000077563", true, 2, here);
    return uint2str(uint(client.Array()));
  }
  function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory ) {
    if (_i == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    uint j = _i;
    uint len;
    while (j != 0) {
        len++;
        j /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
    uint k = len - 1;
    while (_i != 0) {
        bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
        _i /= 10;
    }
    return string(bstr);
  }
  function() external payable{}
  }
```

Whenever i call creation function of BankA in Truffle, it represents length of the onboarded array equal to "1" that is true:

[image]

But whenever i call creation function of BankB, it represents "1" again while it should be "2".

[image]

What is the problem and is there any solution? Thank you.

Comment: This question is not clear. Please post an example that compiles with indenting to be readable, clearly describe the steps to replicate the problem and the result you expected/want.

Comment: In function `creation`, you do `customer client=new customer()`. So what exactly did you expect from a new customer, to somehow know about total customer count??? Also, as mentioned above - your question is chaotic, and as not mentioned above - there are missing definitions in your code, like - what exactly is `Array`???

Comment: In customer's smart contract, prime function sets some KYC information that BankA supplies them and after that pushes address of BankA on onboarded array. Length of the array is zero in first and after client.prime(...) in creation it will be "1". Codes of BankA are qual to codes of BankB. But whenever BankB runs client.prime(...) length of that array doesn't be equal to "2" and be "1" again.

Comment: I had forgotten adding Array() function in customer's smart contract because of copying Notepad. In the end of customer's code it added.

Comment: This array is in the customer contract. Obviously, whenever you create a new customer instance, the initial length of this array is 0, and after you push an address to this array, its length becomes 1. Each customer instance holds an independent array.

Comment: Does this mean onboarded array that BankB be pushed on it is independent of onbarded array that BankA be pushed on it?

Comment: Two different contracts - two different arrays. And BTW, this has nothing to do with Solidity. You'd get the same behavior in every programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we define `customer` contract with `new customer();` in `BankA` and `BankB`, that means `BankA` and `BankB` access to default data of `customer`. Default data is that same data was embedded in smart contract before deployment process. To change the values should apply the below command in banks contracts:

```
customer(“address of customer contract”).prime("Alireza Kiakojouri","5000077563", true, 2, here);
```

After that, banks will access the changed or updated values.

Thus, just replace

```
 customer client=new customer();
 client.prime(Alireza Kiakojouri","5000077563", true, 2, here);
```

with

```
customer(“address of customer contract”).prime("Alireza Kiakojouri","5000077563", true, 2, here);
```

Answer (score 2):

So, don't use `new` in `BankA`. It doesn't give you what you want. To access to current state of a contract you need to use `interface` or you can interact with the smart contract immediately if you have the called contract's Solidity code and import it to the `.sol` file in that the caller contract is there. The link below describes how to use `interface`:

https://dev.to/damcosset/ethereum-development-interfaces-and-function-modifiers-4e4f

Immediately interaction is fully similar to `interface` but you need to import the called `.sol` file.

Answer (score 1):

In general, using `new` keyword, gets a new instance with the default state. When you use `new customer();` it gives you the `customer` contract by its initial state. To call a contract by its current state you should use

`customer(<address>)`

After that you can call its function by something like this:

`customer(<address>).prime(Arg1, Arg2, ...)`